# Listen to Event When Array Is Populate (Array.push(object))

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to listen to a Javascript array and invoke an event once the array has been populate ( have at lest one object in that array)

(Javascript, Jquery it doesn't matter to me)

How can I do it ?

Comment: You want to invoke an event every time the array has a new value added to it, or when the array is 'fully' populated (if so, you'll have to define what that means)?

Comment: I want to invoke only once, once I know its not empty.
( there isn't a possibility to pull object (delete object) only insert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**METHOD 1** *You can modify the code where you are pushing the array*

In your code where you are pushing the value inside the array add the piece of code to trigger the event.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(1);
// Trigger Event Here
```

**METHOD 2** *You can not modify the code where you are pushing the array*

```
// arr is the global array you want to check
var intArr = setInterval(function(){
  if(arr.length>0)
  {
    // Trigger Event.
    clearInterval(intArr); // To stop setInterval() when event is triggered
  }
},100);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
 Array.prototype.myPush=function(value){
       this.push(value);
       alert('value added');
    
    }
    var arr=[1,2];
    arr.myPush(3)
```